# Gradle Liquibase SSH tunnel creating to Aurora Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, gradle, ssh, liquibase, amazon-aurora

need your help,

I need to connect to AWS Aurora Postgresql using liquibase, it's already configured for local machine, and works fine, but have issues with ssh configuration  to it.

I'm using `id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.10.1'`, and `id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.4'`
I'm able to run command directly on host machine, like getting date `execute ('date')` below, but have no idea why liquibase fails with
`Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  The connection attempt failed.`

here is my build.gradle setting:

```
ssh.settings {
knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
logging = 'stdout'
identity = file("${System.properties['user.home']}/myfolder/.ssh/id_rsa")}

remotes {
  dev {
    host = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    port = 22
    user = 'ec2-user'
    identity = file("${System.properties['user.home']}/myfolder/.ssh/id_rsa")
  }
}


ssh.run {
        session(remotes.dev) {
            forwardLocalPort port: 5432, hostPort: 5432
            execute ('date')

            liquibase {
                activities {
                    main {
                        //changeLogFile changeLog
                        url 'jdbc:postgresql://xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres'
                        username feedSqlUserDev
                        password feedSqlUserPasswordDev
                        logLevel 'debug'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me with it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing a direct ssh connect from the system you are running liquibase from?  Sometimes, if it is the first time you have ever connected to a system, the system prompts you to add the target's unique identity to the known_hosts file.  After you do that, automated processes can move forward w/o being blocked by a system prompt.

Comment: hi, yes, I connect to the machine by putty ssh tunnel, but cannot configure ssh on gradle side :(

Answer (score 1):

Also had to connect to SSH bastion host before running liquibase updates. My solution is based on https://github.com/int128/gradle-ssh-plugin/issues/246 answer by the plugin author.

Here is my setup:

```
ssh.settings {
    knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
    logging = 'stdout'
    identity = file("${System.properties['user.home']}/.ssh/id_rsa")
}

remotes {
    bastion {
        host = '<hostname>'
        user = '<username>'
    }
}
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile '...'
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5438/***'
            username '***'
            password '***'
            driver 'org.postgresql.Driver'
        }
    }
}
task('sshTunnelStart') {
    doFirst {
        project.ext.ready = new CountDownLatch(1)
        project.ext.done = new CountDownLatch(1)
        Thread.start {
            ssh.run {
                session(remotes.bastion) {
                    forwardLocalPort port: 5438,
                            host: '<real db hostname>',
                            hostPort: 5432
                    project.ready.countDown()
                    project.done.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // liquibase update timeout
                }
            }
        }
        ready.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // start tunnel timeout
    }
}
task('sshTunnelStop') {
    doLast {
        // teardown tunnel
        project.done.countDown()
    }
}
update.dependsOn(sshTunnelStart)
update.finalizedBy(sshTunnelStop)
```

Note that in liquibase config I use localhost:5438 as it is a local port forwarded to the remote. Later the same port is used in forwardLocalPort as a 'port' parameter. 'host' parameter is set to the remote database host, and 'hostPort' is accordingly the database port. The last part of the config adds dependencies between tasks to liquibase update and start/stop the tunnel.

Comment: is this your `liquibase.properties` file?

Comment: @Andrey, that's part of the main build.gradle, but can be in any of the includes, I suppose. Definitely not in the properties file